# Glympse API - ticket sender's nickname?

Tags: glympse

Is there any way to determine a ticket sender's nickname (or to add metadata to a ticket)?  I have user accounts in my app & I don't want another user's ticket to be viewable by another user after logging out & this seems like it would be the best way to accomplish it (unless there's someone way to "clear" ticket cache)

Answer (score 1):

Glympse API Lite provides you with a way to set sender's nickname/avatar programmatically through IGlympse::setNickname() and IGlympse::setAvatar() methods. There are corresponding getters for both properties.

The ability to wipe user's account is not currently exposed in Glympse API Lite. We will consider adding it in the next build.